# Remove the last number of a line (CSV File)

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

I have thousands of lines like the following in notepad++.

eg :

```
"some string ",0,0,0,0,0,2,4,3,1,0,10
```

But for each line what I need is something like in the following:

```
"some string ",0,0,0,0,0,2,4,3,1,0
```

That is, I need the last number to be removed together with the comma. I think I have the issue in matching the string part. I mean, `"some string"`.

Anyone knows the regular expression for this?

Comment: Is it the same string at the beginning of every line?

Comment: no...it isn't...some different strings...and the numbers are different too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
,\s*\d+$
```

with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

The end of a line can be matched with `$`.
So this should work:

```
,\d+$
```

Replace this just with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Search for

```
("some string".*),\d+$
```

and replace with

```
$1
```

to get rid of `,10` (or any number) on each line that starts with `"some string"`.

---

### Example:

Before:

```
"some string",0,0,0,0,0,2,4,3,1,0,10
"some other string",0,0,0,0,0,2,4,3,1,0,10
```

After:

```
"some string",0,0,0,0,0,2,4,3,1,0
"some other string",0,0,0,0,0,2,4,3,1,0,10
```

The other answers would work if you're doing it on all lines but I was unsure from your question whether you needed to match a particular string.

Comment: It wasn't for a specific string. There are several different strings. string shouldn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Replace `,\s*\d+$` with `\1`
[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: `\1` is the first capture group. You aren't capturing anything in your regex, so `\1` is nothing which is why it still works, but you don't need it.

Comment: @Matt ohh.. I understand it. Thanks for your valuable Comment.